# How can I copy binary data in Windows (preferably with Notepad++)?

Tags: windows, notepad++, clipboard

I want to duplicate some binary data. The normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> command doesn't work in my editor (Notepad++), it copies data only up to the first `NUL` char. Is there any workaround?

Comment: The way data is stored in the clipboard depends on how the application is using the clipboard API. Notepad++ is a text editor, so it probably stores content as text. If you view the content in some hex editor, it'll probably let you copy it using one of the other [standard types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168(v=vs.85).aspx) (and possibly other registered types). To get a full answer, you'd better provide more details, like the source of the binary data and the target.

Comment: vim comes with a commandline tool called `xxd` which is a really useful hexdump and hexdump *assembler* (`xxd -r`). Though clipboards aren't exactly reliable when it comes to binary data, as characters outside the ASCII range can get lost in translation, or the data could be mangles while whatever you're pasting it into decides it would be a *great* idea to encode it as UTF-8/16. Base64 was designed to be resistant to that, so I'd recommend getting a Windows copy of the `base64` coreutil and putting it in your `%PATH%` so you always have it handy. `base64`, `base64 -d`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the `Edit` menu of Notepad++ (I'm using v5.9.2) under `Paste Special` there are actions to Copy, Cut, and Paste Binary Content.

[image: Submenu of Paste Special in Edit menu of Notepad++]

Answer (score 2):

The Notepad++ MIME Tools plugin and Base64 Encode/Decode feature can be used to copy small binary files (typically small jar or zip files) between remote systems using the clipboard.

1. Open the Binary file binary1.bin in Notepad++
2. Edit -> Select All (Ctrl+A)
3. Plugins -> MIME Tools -> Base64 Encode
4. Edit -> Select All (Ctrl+A)
5. Edit -> Copy (Ctrl+C)
6. Edit -> Undo (Ctrl+Z)
7. Move focus to a new Notepad++ tab
8. Edit -> Paste (Ctrl+v)
9. Edit -> Select All (Ctrl+A)
10. Plugins -> MIME Tools -> Base64 Decode
11. File -> Save As... binary2.bin

[image: Plugins -> MIME Tools -> Base64 Encode selected]
[image: Plugins -> MIME Tools -> Base64 Decode selected]

Comment: I used this method for an excel document and it worked wonderfully.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it.  I sometimes use this with an AutoHotKey script that "types out" my clipboard content after a short delay.  If I have a virtual machine connected to a remote desktop window to another virtual machine or other weird tunneling setups the clipboard contents don't always paste thru correctly and I can't count on special characters getting sent correctly.  With the script I copy the encoded file to send.  Run the script and click into the destination editor and the file is typed out.   Its a hack but it always seems to work.